What is a word for someone who uses power/authority for good?
I am looking for a word or term for someone who is powerful or holds authority and also uses it with good morality.

Any sort of power or authority? Kings and presidents? Dictators? Tribal leaders? Generals? Corporate bosses and billionaires? Public intellectuals without formal power, just respect? Celebrities and pop idols who have power or authority over their fans? Religious leaders, prophets, seers, priests, and theologians? Criminals, spies, and conspirators? Good leader will describe some but not all of these. (You will note there is no single word for those who are powerful or hold authority.)

Such a one might be a benevolent dictator. Wikipedia has:

A benevolent dictatorship is a government in which an authoritarian leader exercises absolute political power over the state, but is perceived to do so with regard for the benefit of the population as a whole.


Not everybody 'who is powerful or holds authority' (which is what the question is about) uses that power in a dictatorial way.

@jsw29 - true, that's why I qualified it with "might be"

A statesman

2: a wise, skillful, and respected political leader

MW https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/statesman
It’s interesting that the language has not yet bothered to attack this as sexist and offer or demand “states-person” or “stateswoman.”

statesmen can be corrupt.

I agree. Many statesmen are corrupt.

An enlightened despot uses his power for common good of his subjects.
More information : Who were considered Enlightened despots, and why?

Not everybody 'who is powerful or holds authority' (which is what the question is about) uses that power in a despotic way.

An ethical person. Like any other.
Read about it here:
ethical

Not every ethical person 'is powerful or holds authority'.

The question was: what's the word for a person who uses power/authority for good? The word is: An ethical person. So, it really does not matter if you have power/authority but if you do, you are like any other ethical person. There is no "special word" for one with power/authority who is ethical. You deliberately turned around the idea. But that is not the question.

The question asks about a person 'who is powerful or holds authority', not just a person who uses it for good if and in so far as the person has it.

@Jsw29 Why are you turning it around? The person has power and authority and they use it for good. So, they are ethical. It doesn't say insofar as they use it for good, does it? That would be a different question.

It is you who said that 'it really does not matter if you have power/authority but if you do . . .'.

@jsw29 Yes, because that is my point. If you do good, you are ethical with or without power. My point is that there is no special word for doing good for people with power or authority. They are ethical people just like any other ethical person.

If you believe that 'there is no special word for doing good for people with power or authority', which is indeed a perfectly reasonable answer to this question, then that (there is no word that the OP is seeking) should be in the answer, as its core.

Well, my opinion is that Op's question is rather ambiguous and hard to understand, so I'd rather not to answer such a question.

@LukeL That's an interesting opinion for a participant who signed up just two days ago....
